# $\exp(a)\exp(b) = \exp(a+b)$

Tags: exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation

I found this in the prologue of Rudin's book.  The formula tries to relate this exponential addition using power series.  It is clear that if we start from the right we can write it as a sum of binomial expansion terms divided by factorial.
If we come from the left, I am a bit vexed.  Working out the terms by hand

```
(1 + a + a^2/2 + a^3/6 + a^4/24 + a^5/120 + ...)(1 + b + b^2/2 + b^3/6 + b^4/24 + b^5/120 + ...) =
 1 + b + b^2/2 + b^3/6 + b^4/24 + b^5/120 + ... +
 a + ab + ab^2/2 + ab^3/6 + ab^4/24 + ab^5/120 + ... +
(a^2 + a^2b + a^2b^2/2 + a^2b^3/6 + a^2b^4/24 + a^2b^5/120 + ... +)/2
(a^3 + a^3b + a^2b^3/2 + a^3b^3/6 + a^3b^4/24 + a^3b^5/120 + ... +)/6
```

Here I am just factoring each term of exp(a) series with the entire series of exp(b).

```
(a+b)^0/1 = 1
(a+b)^1/1 = a + b
(a+b)^2/2 = a^2/2 + ab + b^2/2
(a+b)^3/6 = a^3/6 + a^2*b/2 + a*b^2/2 + b^3/6
```

I am able to visually see that if we take diagonals each one works out to a binomial expansion divided by factorial.

What is the actual mathematical concept for this?  It looks possibly related to Pascal's triangle.

Comment: You must know that you may reorder infinite series without changing it's value.  This follows because the series for exp converges absolutely. Maybe it's easier to keep track by using $\sum$ notation like $$\exp x =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$.

Comment: Yes I understand that I am assuming the sum is invariant to rearrangement for x<0 via absolute convergence but how does one write out these diagonals in a closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start writing $\exp(x+y)$ as power series, and use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to expand $(x+y)^n$:
$$\begin{align}
e^{x+y}
&= \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac1{n!}(x+y)^n\\
&= \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac1{n!}\sum_{j=0}^n \binom nj x^j y^{n-j}\\
\end{align}$$
Now denote $f(x)[x^k]$ as the coefficient at $x^k$ in the power series expansion of $f(x)$. Applying $[x^k]$ to the series above, the inner sum reduces to just one term at most due to $j\stackrel!=k$:
$$\begin{align}
e^{x+y}[x^k]
&= \sum_{n\geqslant k}\frac1{n!} \binom nk y^{n-k}\\
&\stackrel{1.}= \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac1{(n+k)!} \binom {n+k}k y^n\\
&\stackrel{2.}= \frac 1{k!} \sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{k!}{(n+k)!} \frac{(n+k)!}{k!n!} y^n\\
&= \frac 1{k!} \underbrace{\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{1}{n!}y^n}_{\displaystyle{=e^y}}\\
\end{align}$$

1. Replace the summation index as $n\mapsto n+k$.
2. Extends by $k!$, and expands the binomial coefficient.

The last line is what we wanted to show because
$$\begin{align}
e^x e^y
&= \left(\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{y^n}{n!}\right)\\
&= \sum_{k\geqslant 0}\left(\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{y^n}{n!}\right)x^k\\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Well 8 months later, I took another fresh stab at it and got it.  I found it more instructive to just literally brute force the binomial expansion product of e^x*e^y and then use the rearrangement (it turned out the mention for absolute convergence was a hint on this)  and then one can show that this is of the form e^(x + y)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely Pascal's triangle.

On one hand, you expand the powers $(a+b)^n$ divided by $n!$, giving coefficients $\dfrac{\displaystyle\binom nk}{n!}=\dfrac1{k!(n-k)!}$.

On the other, you form products like $\dfrac{a^k}{k!}\dfrac{b^j}{j!}$ and group all terms such that $k+j=n$ or $j=n-k$.